# How to implement Repository Pattern on separated modules?

Tags: android

I'm implement the Repository Pattern on Android. The problem starts when trying to implement the `SharedPreferences` as a Repository.

I want my data, or repository layer, to be free of android-specific clases or components. So, I can't reference a `SharedPreferences` object since it requires a `Context`.

The modules in my project within Android Studio are summarized as follows:

```
|-> moduleApp       // an android-application module
|-> moduleViewModel // an android-library module
|-> moduleData      // a java-library module with no access to Context object
```

My solution to this is to create an interface in the `moduleData` module like:

```
interface PreferencesRepository {
    fun retrievePreference() : String
}
```

Then, implement the above interface in the `moduleApp` module. The `moduleApp` module will be something like:

```
|-> moduleApp
|-----> com.app.ui   // classes related to UI (Fragment, Activity, etc)
|-----> com.app.di   // classes related to dependency injection
|-----> com.app.foo  // more classes specific to the app module
|-----> com.app.data // data package inside the app module
|---------> PreferencesRepositoryImpl.kt
```

So, the implementation will be this:

```
class PreferencesRepositoryImpl(prefs: SharedPreferences) {
    fun retrievePreference(): String {
        return prefs.getString(...)
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I need a SharedPreferences repository, I'd just inject the `PreferencesRepository` interface via dependency injection.

I think this is the right way to go to have separated modules, it also doesn't break the dependency rule. But seems like there may be a better approach related to how to depend on Android specific classes from other layers.

Has anyone solved this problem with a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate cache module that will deal with storing and fetching data from `SharedPreferences` in future if you want to swap `SharedPreferences` with something else you can do that without changing any code in repository implementation instead changing code only in cache module and this would make code much more readable too, you can have a look at this project for help in implementation

https://github.com/bufferapp/clean-architecture-components-boilerplate